# How to parametrize the host in style content references?

Tags: css, deployment, web, path

What is the simplest way to set a parametric host in one or several CSS style sheets, for static content like images?

By *parametric host*, i mean having the host define somewhere else, while the path is standing, so that the host definition can be changed for different levels of deployment.

While this is trivial to do for javascript included images, and while a `<base>` url is provided for HTML, i don't know how to achieve the same result with style assets.

Notes:

- the question is about standard CSS, without preprocessors
- using relative paths will not work, since the style sheets need to be loaded from different domains

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i found out that using relative paths will work, since relative URIs are computed from the position of the style sheet, not the serving page (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/uri)

In my case, then, the best thing to do is to have relative URIs, and have the assets deployed together with the style sheet